# What can I do with an 18-55 mm kit lens?

Tags: nikon-d5100

I've had my nikon D5100 camera for over a year and don't have too many shots I'm really proud of. I feel uninspired and wondering if there are any cool tricks or shots with a slow shutter speed? I also don't know much about the settings and basically only shoot in auto mode. I need help moving forward, but I'm not sure if the next step is a new lens with different capabilities or a better understanding of the settings and what I'm doing.